# Import my own files into the electron renderer process

Tags: electron

This seems really dumb, but I need help for importing some source code into the renderer process in electron:

I have an electron app:
index.html (loads window.js with a  tag)
- index.js
- window.js
- useful_functions.js

In `window.js`, I want to import some functions from `useful_functions.js`, so I've tried the following:

```
// fails with: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
import { very_useful } from './useful_functions.js';

// fails with: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
const { very_useful } = require('./useful_functions.js');

// fails with: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
require('electron').remote.require('./useful_functions.js')
```

I also tried the `nodeIntegration` flag, but that didn't help either

**Note**: I'm not trying to import npm modules but my own code, in an other file right next to it.

I'm looking for examples, but I only find super small samples with just the basic files. (Or huge apps like atom that would take me a while to figure out)

I don't have webpack setup for this project yet, but I'm sure there is a simpler way to do this very basic task...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are using ES6 features like import and require. Have you added a transpiler like Babel to your project?

Answer (score 0):

In `index.html`, use `require()` instead of loading `window.js` with a tag, i.e., replace:

```
<script src="window.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script>require('./window.js');</script>
```

Then, in `window.js`, the following statement should work too:

```
const { very_useful } = require('./useful_functions.js');
```

Note that `nodeIntegration: true` is needed in the options passed to `new BrowserWindow()` anyway:

```
webPreferences:
{
    nodeIntegration: true
}
```

See:

- [Node Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

> Functions and objects are added to the root of a module by
>   specifying additional properties on the special exports object.
>
> Variables local to the module will be private, because the module is
>   wrapped in a function by Node.js (see **module wrapper**).

- [Module Wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper)

> Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a
>   function wrapper that looks like the following:
>
> (function(exports, **require**, module, __filename, __dirname) {
>   // Module code actually lives in here
>   });